# How to read standard input into std::stringstream until Ctrl-D (end of transmission)?

Tags: c++, stringstream

How do I take standard input of several lines and store it into a `std::streamstring` until the user presses <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to signal end of input? I'd like to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974402/reading-getline-from-cin-into-a-stringstream-c) but for variable lines of input. How can I check for end of transmission signal as signaled by a <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> press by the user?

```
    string std_input;
    stringstream stream(std_input);
    while (getline(cin, std_input))
        stream(std_input);
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) "Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question."

Comment: Which part can I be more clear on. The program compiles and doesn't throw any error. I want to get variable user input from stdin and store it into a stream. I linked to an example of a similar question but I want to extend it for variable lines of input.

Comment: You say you'd like to read in several lines from standard input and store it in a stringstream, then have code that answers your own question. What's the problem? What information do you need from us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way in my opinion is to pass underlaying buffer of `std::cin` to string stream, since it has overload for `std::basic_streambuf`

```
std::ostringstream sstream;
sstream << std::cin.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
string std_input;
stringstream stream;
while (getline(cin, std_input)) {
  stream << std_intput << endl;
}
```

Comment: Recommend `'\n'` in place of `endl` off general principals. It's not going to matter much with a string stream, but should this code be ported to write  file the flush built into in `endl` will hurt performance grievously.